# Show all Fullname tabs to everyone

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

Using Docusign's SDK for PHP, I have the following code to print tabs into the documents to be signed:

```
$tabs = new Tabs([
                'full_name_tabs' => [
                    new FullName([
                        'anchor_string' => "****fullname-$key****",  
                        'anchor_units' => "pixels",  
                        'anchor_x_offset' => "-5",  
                        'anchor_y_offset' => "0",
                        'bold' => true,
                    ]),
                ],
                'text_tabs' => [
                    new Text([
                        'anchor_string' => "****fullname-$key****",
                        'anchor_units' => "pixels",
                        'anchor_x_offset' => "-5",
                        'anchor_y_offset' => "13",
                        'value' => $signer['role'],                        
                        'bold' => true,
                    ]),
                ],
                'sign_here_tabs' => [
                    new SignHere([
                        'anchor_string' => "****signature-$key****",  
                        'anchor_units' => "pixels",  
                        'anchor_x_offset' => "5",  
                        'anchor_y_offset' => "40",
                    ]),
                ],
            ]);
```

However, each signer only sees their tabs or the tabs of the signers that have come before him. I need all signers to see all full_name and text tabs at any moment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the "When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field to all recipients" is checked in your settings.
Go to "Settings" (admin only at the top menu) and then select "Sending Settings" in the left menu.

[image]